# Hadoop streaming with multiple input files

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I want to build an inverted index from a set of files with Hadoop using the Streaming API. The documentation always refers to using a file whose lines have the entries to the mapper to be fed. But in this case, I have multiple input files, and I need the mappers to process only one file at a time. Is there a way to accomplish that. For preprocessing reasons, I need the input to be like this, and I cannot have the input in the classic line = key, value format that the documentation refers.

Answer (score 0):

By default a mapper only processes one file, unless you use an input class that allow combine inputs like CombineFileInputFormat.

Then, if you have 10 files you will end with 10 mappers and each of them will process only one file. If you are only using mappers (not reducers) that will end in 10 outputs files (one for each mapper).

In the other side, if you have enough big splittable files, it is possible that one file be processed by several mappers at the same time.